# Excel - how to find all values with matching keys?

Tags: excel

In a sorted list, I'm trying to find all values in 'B' for each person in 'A' and display them as shown in column 'D'.  I've gotten as far as what I have in column 'F' and I know how to concatenate the values if I had them but I'm stuck.  How can I find all the values in 'B' that correspond to 'A'? (without vba)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vomLh.jpg

I'm new to excel so I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: please review the [tag:textjoin] questions. The answer is there.

Comment: My problem isn't with concatenating, it's with finding what values I need to concatenate.

Comment: Is it just me that can't see the image? I just see a black empty page. Please include data as an insert no image. You can use [online table generators](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for example to format the data and then insert that; highlight it; press ctrl + K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is what you're looking for:

IF(A5=A4,"",TEXTJOIN("-",FALSE,(B5:INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-1+COUNTIF(A:A,A5))))))

(I hope the picture uploaded :-)

@Jeeped was correct in using textjoin(), which I wasn't familiar with, but you're primary criteria was for (essentially) matching rows. Conventional thought is to loop through matching names, but loops = VBA, which you want to avoid.  So, the alternative is knowing the length of the list.

Breaking down the formula:
IF(A5=A4,    # because the list is sorted, we display where name rows are  different
    "",       # otherwise just return a blank
TEXTJOIN(  # (thanks @Jeeped -- this made the work a lot easier)
            "-",    # your list delimiter
            FALSE,  # False (include) True(ignore empty cells -- your call
            (B5:    # use the range  - starting from the current 'B' Cell   (note same      row as (A5) through...
             INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-1+COUNTIF(A:A,A5))))))

Indirect says: pass the 'created value' as if an entered reference, but in this case, the 'number of cell {down}' is determined by the countif(), that is 'how many of the keys' are in the list. The number is overstated by (+1) because were already sitting on the starting row, therefore (-1).  So, this parameter starts with "B5:" and appends (as an indirect()), the current row as a number MINUS 1 PLUS the total count() of cells in column A that matches the value of column A in the current row, EG: ROW=5, Count = 2, => 'B5:B'+(5-1+2) 
returns: 'B5:B7' to the TextJoin().

[Screen shot of Formula & results...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWLeO.png)